# Minecraft worlds do not save

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

About a week ago, my worlds stopped saving when I exit on single player.

I tried a lot of ideas and looked around the Internet. I then deleted the .minecraft folder and the Minecraft launcher. I re-downloaded Minecraft and the worlds were saving on exit.

I made several worlds and all continued to save on exit.  I then resumed using my regular texture pack and the worlds stopped saving.

I am suspicious that my texture pack is the source of this problem.

I saw another question and the person also downloaded a new texture pack.  The thing is I've been using this texture pack since 1.8.0 and never encountered this problem.  I have modified it a little, but I don't think this is the problem.

Is my texture pack broken or corrupted?

And if so, can and how can I fix it?

Update:

I got a new .minecraft folder, made a world and saved it. It saved and all was good.  I then downloaded and installed optifine 1.10.2 for the new .minecraft folder.  It stopped saving the worlds. I logged in and out many times and at first it was saving but gradually it stopped saving.

I don't know whether my texture pack was causing the problem because this time I used only optifine with no texture pack.

Comment: It's a problem with your resource/texture pack,

Comment: welp... ya i figured, but is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but someone else might

Comment: Go to your launcher and press edit profile. Then select laucher visibility and click on Keep launcher open. Go to your world and walk around for a few seconds then pause. Then check your launcher. Does it say "Saving Chunks for Level"?

Comment: Yes it does say that(            [18:55:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving and pausing game...
[18:55:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'Void'/Overworld
[18:55:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'Void'/Nether
[18:55:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'Void'/The End               ), but it still does not save :/

Answer (score -2):

Its possible that your computer is full if so delete some files if not delete mine craft and download it agian this might fix the problem

Comment: your texture pack could be the source if so then delete the texture pack and minecraft and then redownload Minecraft

Comment: If you're saying my computer does not have enough space for minecraft to write changes in the save file.... I have 311 GB left and I redownloaded minecraft twice.

Comment: well then i have no idea

Comment: did you delete the texture pack

Comment: I deleted the .minecraft folder ( i had a backup) and minecraft made a new one which has default texture pack and it saved the worlds, but I don't want to get rid of my texture pack to play minecraft. I worked on it so hard. D:

Comment: SO u made it it okay the could be the problem if so put it in a flashdrive and then delete it